# Convert Equivalent Rails ORM command for SQL Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a SQL query to be converted to Rails ORM (ActiveRecord)

```
SELECT * FROM txactions
  INNER JOIN accounts
  WHERE accounts.item_accountId = 15845388
    AND accounts.id = txactions.account_id
```

Comment: `Txaction.includes(:account).where('accounts.item_accountId = ? ',15845388 )` try this

Comment: You can also try this `Txaction.joins("INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = txactions.account_id").where("accounts.item_accountId = ? ",15845388 )` OR `Txaction.joins(:accounts).where('accounts.item_accountId = ? ',15845388 )`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Txaction.joins("INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = txactions.account_id").where("accounts.item_accountId = ?", 15845388)
```

**OR**

```
Txaction.joins(:accounts).where("accounts.item_accountId = ?", 15845388)
```